# Choose what values to output from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this to print values from an array.

```
<?php foreach ($product->data['attributes'] as $attribute => $option) {
   echo '<li>'. t('@attribute: @options', array('@attribute' => $attribute, '@options' => implode(', ', (array)$option))) .'</li>';
} ?>
```

The code above prints everything from the attributes array:

```
[products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Duration] => Array
                                    (
                                        [4] => 2 Years
                                    )

                                [Anchor Text] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => asdf
                                    )

                                [URL] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => asdddddd
                                    )

                                [Feed ID] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 32845898
                                    )

                            )
                    )
            )

    )
```

I only want to print the [URL] and [Feed ID]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo($product->data['attributes']['URL'])
echo($product->data['attributes']['Feed ID'])
```

---

Update:

It looks like the values of your individual "attributes" are, themselves, arrays.
Try the following instead (it combines all the values of the array, separated with commas).

```
echo(implode(',', (array)$product->data['attributes']['URL']));
echo(implode(',', (array)$product->data['attributes']['Feed ID']));
```

Comment: That's what I thought initially but the output only echos 'array', as in the string 'array'. Ex. URL: Array.